# mantener los elementos del div al cargar más contenido

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Cargo un contenido en un `div` por medio de `$('#divID').load('/Historial/Historial/11/20')` y lo carga bien, pero cuando quiero cargar mas contenido en ese `div` se borra lo que ya estaba anteriormente

**¿Hay alguna forma de cargar más contenido sin eliminar lo que estaba anteriormente en el `div`?**

La estructura donde se encuentra el `div` es la siguiente:

```
<div id='Historial'>
    <div id='divID'></div>
    <div id="Carga" style="text-align:center;display:none;">
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, con [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

Html:

```
<div id="divID">Mi contenido....</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#divID').append('<span>Más contenido</span>');
```

El resultado sería algo así:

```
<div id='Historial'>
    <div id='divID'>
      Mi contenido...
      <span>Más contenido</span>
    </div>
    <div id="Carga" style="text-align:center;display:none;">
      <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
      <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

También está [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), el cual funciona con una sintaxis distinta:

Html:

```
<div id="divID">Mi contenido....</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('<span>Más contenido</span>').appendTo('#divID');
```

---

Edición para dar un ejemplo práctico según el caso de la pregunta:

```
// carga de primer contenido (se puede utilizar $.get() también)
$('#divID').load('/Historial/Historial/11/20');

// carga del segundo contenido y anexarlo al elemento
$.get('/Historial/Historial/21/30', function(data) {$('#divID').append(data);});
```

Comment: y como podría aplicarlo si el nuevo contenido que voy a agregar lo traigo desde `$('#divID').load('/Historial/Historial/21/30')`?

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que `.load()` es muy similar a `.get()`, y de la forma que lo usas es casi intercambiable, tienes varias opciones: 1. usar los parámetros adicionales de `.load()` 2. simplemente usar `.get()`, el cual no es más que un método más sencillo de utilizar `.ajax()`. 3. usar `.ajax()`. En cualquiera de los 3 casos, puedes guardar la información recibida y pasarla a donde quieras.

Comment: Entendí mejor el contexto con `.ajax()` a diferencia de `.get()` utilizando el  `appendTo()` Gracias @Shaz

Comment: Agregué un ejemplo con `.get()`